# I cant get my ionic app to open in iOS emulator

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework

My new ionic app won't run in the iOS emulator.

Its a fresh install of ionic and Xcode, these are my steps:

```
npm install -g ionic

ionic start myApp tabs

ionic cordova platform add ios

ionic cordova build ios

ionic cordova emulate ios
```

Then I get the following error:

> No target specified for emulator. Deploying to undefined simulator
>   /localhost/myApp/platforms/ios/build/emulator/MyApp.app/Info.plist
>   file not found.

According to this thread ([Fresh Ionic Fails to Emulate iOS 12 - Info.plist file not found](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/fresh-ionic-fails-to-emulate-ios-12-info-plist-file-not-found/142291/7)) it should work with the following command:

```
ionic cordova emulate ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
```

But then I get the following error:

> No target specified for emulator. Deploying to undefined simulator
>   Device type "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.undefined" could not be found.

And then according to this thread ([Issues starting iOS simulator from CLI](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/issues-starting-ios-simulator-from-cli/107376)) it should work by updating ios-sim like this:

```
cd platforms/ios/cordova && npm install ios-sim@latest
```

But I still get the following error:

> No target specified for emulator. Deploying to undefined simulator
>   Device type "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.undefined" could not be found.

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.10.2 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.12.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.4
   @angular/cli                  : 7.2.4
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.4.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : ios 4.5.0
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 3.1.2, (and 4 other plugins)

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.9.4
   ios-sim    : 7.0.0
   NodeJS     : v10.15.1 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.4.1
   OS         : macOS Mojave
   Xcode      : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
```

Comment: Can you put the output of `ionic info` in your question? I'll compare it to mine.

Comment: Only difference I can see between our environments apart from the fact that you are using Ionic 4 while I'm using v3, is that you Cordova iOS platform seems older, mine is `ios 4.5.5` while yours is only `4.5.0` try remove and add the platform again perhaps?

Comment: I've tried to manually downgrade cordova platforms to 4.5.0. It was 4.5.5 before

Comment: Yeah this is pretty weird, probably another dumb question but have you tried removing the platform and adding it again - `ionic cordova platform rm ios` then `ionic corodva platform add ios`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that as well

Answer (score 4):

The problem lie with ios-sim package which couldn't detect running simulators.
Updating to 8.0.1 with the following steps resolved the issue for me.

force update ios-sim to a working version

1. **IMPORTANT needs to be done from inside the platforms/ios/cordova directory.**

   `cd platforms/ios/cordova && npm install ios-sim@8.0.1`
2. #### check if devices are now listed, takes a few seconds

   `ionic cordova emulate --list`
3. #### installs appscript if not installed already

   `ionic cordova build ios`
4. #### try to deploy to simulator

   `ionic cordova emulate --release --prod --livereload ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"`

This will find any running simulator and deploy the app

Answer (score 0):

Try just building the project and then running it from Xcode instead first.

- `ionic cordova build ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"`

Then open the `platforms/ios` folder in Xcode and you'll be able to run it from there plus see any errors there may be with the project. When you eventually decide to push the app to the store you'll need to do this anyway.

**EDIT**

Then try targeting a specific emulator:

- `ionic cordova emulate ios --list` get list of available targets to copy into the next command.
- `ionic cordova emulate --livereload ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0" --target="iPhone-X, 12.1"` example targeting iPhone XR.

Comment: Yes but then I can't use the livereload feature :|

Comment: Just tried it on my machine, it's working as expected when I run `ionic cordova emulate --release --prod --livereload ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"` that's testing a prod build.

Comment: Try targeting a specific emulator, I'll update my answer.

Comment: tbh I've never used the livereload feature of emulate before now, glad I answered this question now, it's really going to speed things up in the future :-)

Comment: `ionic cordova emulate ios --list` gives me an empty list

Comment: That's weird, stupid question but do you have Xcode or Android Studio installed?

Comment: Yes. It's working fine when I open the project in Xcode and run the Simulator manually

Comment: Damn, yeah now that I've discovered this feature I can see why you'd want it, my only advice would be to go through the Cordova [docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/index.html) for the iOS platform and make sure you've set everything up as described. I'll do some more searching to see why your emulate --list would be empty.

Comment: Have you installed command line tools for xcode - `xcode-select --install`?

Comment: Do you get anything when you run `./platforms/ios/cordova/lib/list-emulator-images` from your project root?

Comment: No, that's empty as well.. it's very weird

Comment: Any follow up on this? Experiencing the same issue after os update

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to a breaking changes on Xcode 10 not already reflected on [ios-sim](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ios-sim). You can check on ion-sim repo issue ["List empty of devices simulator with Xcode 10"](https://github.com/ios-control/ios-sim/issues/234).

The issue have already been fixed but is waiting for a new release submission.

You can continue running your App on emulator directly from Xcode.